# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 no unity dash for default user special compiz config

Tags: compiz, 14.04

I've upgraded my Ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04 using the Ubuntu suggested option, everything went well -- meaning no report of corrupted update or anything - but when I rebooted and logged in again there was no desktop, meaning all I was getting was a black screen and the mouse pointer. I looked through the other threads on here and tried the solutions on there, it didn't really worked.

All I've been able to do was after removing and re-installing the lightdm manager I was able to get the top bar in the logging screen, but after actually logging in with the default user I only get a top bar with File Wiew Help etc and I can't open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Atl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. I had some special compiz configuration in 13.10, but I've removed it and the problem is still not solved. Another thing, if I log in with a guest user I get both the top and side bar in Ubuntu.

If you guys have any idea what I could do it would be appreciated.

L.E.

Thanks for your input but none of them helped sadly.

Dpn I tried to do what you suggested and I couldn't run the first command, I got the following error:

```
 Error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

And, Daniel your solution didn't change anything at all, I already had that files in the place with configured exactly as you suggested.

Is there a way for me to copy the settings from the guest account in the default account? Or a way to compare the 2 configurations and see what's different?

Thanks, any advice would be appreciated!

L.L.E. I fixed it, I don't know if it helps anyone but, what I did was to reinstall the `compiz-core`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz-core
```

and then to remove the files in the `.cache` and `.config` folders

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
```

Hope this helps others!

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

ITs because your lightdm is crashed. Do the following things

Press ALT+CTRL+F1

You will get tt1

Login as username = root

Password what you set for you system

Now enter the following lines

vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf.dpkg-bak //an editor opens b4 u

Delete what is there and add the following lines

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-show-manual-login=true

Also edit the following file

vim /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-show-manual-login=true

Now Restart the system using the following command

init 6 //Reboot system

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+Ctrl+F2, black screen appears.Now, login with your username & password & type this

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

then

`setsid unity`

then Press Alt+Ctrl+F7 to see your desktop

Guest User will show default settings because its a different user. Every user has its own settings.