# Edubuntu 14.04 install, no Unity

Tags: 14.04, edubuntu

I have been trying to install Edubuntu 14
04 on to our Hp workstation xw4200, Intel pentium, 4 SPU 3.2GHz .
I am using a USB boot drive which I created following instructions on edubuntu download section. The installation seems to go fine but upon restart, screen art comes up once and then goes black. I can force a terminal and after some research suspected my nvidia driver.ven the problem. I purged Nvidia driver and installed the one recommended but now it brings up the screen but no further. My video card is NVDIDIA NV37GL Quadro PCI-E Series rev a2

I have gone to terminal and tried the following
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity

sudo shutdown -r now

I have also tried the solutions outlined here:
[Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 no unity dash for default user special compiz config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457501/upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04-no-unity-dash-for-default-user-special-compiz-config)

UPDATED I have removed all NVIDIA Drivers and it works, slowly and with really low resolution. I would love a solution to get the resolution back and full functionality.