# No menu bar and unity launch after upgrading to 14.04; ccsm cannot start

Tags: unity, 14.04, upgrade, compiz

Yesterday I upgraded from 12.10 to 14.04 by `do-release-upgrade`.
Things were Ok after the upgrading.

However today when I logged into my account, no menu bar, no unity launch.
I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the terminal and re-installed Ubuntu-desktop, but it didn't help.

Then I installed compizconfig-settings-manager. But `ccsm` failed with the error message `could not open display`.

The only good news was that when I logged in as guest, the desktop worked fine.

What can I do now?

Updates:

First thank you all.

According to [Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 no unity dash for default user special compiz config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457501/upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04-no-unity-dash-for-default-user-special-compiz-config), I deleted  `~/.config/dconf/user` and    `~/.cache/compizconfig-1` and the problem was solved.

I think this was caused by my own configuration files. And definitely bain's method will work too.

I opened TTY because I failed to run terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I didn't realize `ccsm` couldn't work in that situation.

Thank you once again.

Comment: You could try starting in fallback mode and see if anything runs from there. Could you post the commands you used to 're-install ubuntu-desktop'.

Comment: `ccsm` is a GUI application, you cannot start it in a TTY session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Since it works for guest user but not your normal user, you can fix this by resetting your home directory:

- Switch to virtual terminal with ctrl-alt-f1
- Login to your account
- Do `mkdir ~/bak && mv ~/.* ~/* ~/bak`
- Logout
- Press ctrl-alt-f7 to switch to desktop and log in
- All of your old files are in ~/bak.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the Unity and Compiz

First login into `tty` by pressing `CTRL+ALT+1`

**Note**: Press `ALT+7` to came out from `tty`

1. Download Unity Reset tool from [here](https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb).

   **Note**: It should work with Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 and 13.04.
2. Reset Unity using the following command

   ```
   $ unity-reset
   ```